# GCP Dataflow failing due to BigQuery warning message about Cloud SQL Federated connection not in "query region"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql

I have a Dataflow job (using Apache Beam 2.24.0) that runs a BigQuery query that uses a [Cloud SQL federated query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). A warning message on that query has begun appearing.

> The following connections are located in a different region than the query region: projects/[project-id]/locations/us/connections/[connection-name]. Please recreate the connections in the query region and reference the new connections in your query by 9/30.

The query is being run by Dataflow in region `us-east1`. The connection was created in the US multi-region location. The query also joins in other BigQuery datasets in the US multi-region location.

Note that the documentation on federated queries specifically states that querying a region along with multi-region Bigquery datasets should work *fine*.

**Debugging steps tried**

It's not possible to specify that a Dataflow job runs in a multi-region location. If I try moving the connection, as recommended by the warning message, into the "query region" of `us-east1`, the query then fails because it cannot query the other datasets located in the US multi-region location.

The frustrating bit is that the query successfully runs, but with a warning message. Unfortunately, [Dataflow parses any messages to mean failure](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7c43ab6a8df9b23caa7321fddff9a032a71908f6/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryHelpers.java#L433). The kicker is that this warning to change things by 9/30 first showed up on **9/29**.

Does anyone have a solution for me, other than waiting for Google to fix this bug?

Comment: Is your query working? With your post I understand that your problem is just the warning logs, am I right?